# Align horizontally the start of a text line to the center of the page in HTML

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

Is it possible in HTML to align the start of a text line to the center of page?

Or another option: is it possible to avoid wrapping of the text in a table, but keep the cell width? Just like in Excel by default?

I'm formatting the main blocks of text on my page using centered tables 800px wide, but some lines, which I want to be straight, don't fit into 800px.
http://compositing.tv/Research/MathBehindApplyModes/

Currently, I just put those lines outside of the tables and center them.
But I would like to align the start of these lines with the left side of the main text blocks.

Logically, I need to bring the start of the line to the center of the page first and shift it 400px to the left. Or I could probably create a special table, where the start of the line would be at the start of the cell, but the end would extend further to the right, unless it meets the page border.

Comment: Yes, It can be achieved by wrapping text in a `div with absolute positionning` http://htmlbank.net/?29 but I have doubts that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;"> This is header 1 </h1>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).